# Xcode certificates in anothe mac

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, code-signing, profiles

I'm out of home and I forgot to export my certificate and code signing stuff from my imac. Now I'm having trouble with trying out projects on the device. I downloaded de certificates and everything from the provisioning portal but doesn't work. It seems that the keys are missing.

I suppose I sould go through the whole process again in order to get everything working. My question is: if I through the whole process again, will it be a problem when I get back home? I was thinking in creating a new developer profile caled "macBook dev profile" or similar to have everything clear.

Any feedback on that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the dev certificate, and add that certificate to the existing provisioning profile. You don't need to create separate profiles as such. And these would not interfere with your existing settings on other machines.

It won't be problem even if you create separate profiles, but it would be better to have only one, imho.

Comment: So should I revoke the existing certificate and create a new one?

Comment: No, just edit the existing one. Download the modified profile on your new mac, and it will work. Your existing mac wouldn't need to re-download the profile.

Comment: Sorry, mis-read your comment. DO NOT revoke any CERTIFICATEs. Create a new one. EDIT the PROVISIONING PROFILE to include the newly created certificate.

Comment: I don't see any "Request Ceritificate" button. I guess I should actually revoke my certificate and the create a new one. Maybe it's because I'm an individua developer, not part of a team.

Comment: Oh.. perhaps that is the case. I don't have an individual account so can not say. In this case, you would need to revoke the certificate. This time, export this certificate and import it on the other machine, since the new profile would not contain the older certificate.

Comment: yeah, I'd try that. I'll tell how it goes.

Comment: I finally got somebody to turn on my computer at home and start TeamViewer. I exported the certificates AND the keys from Keychain. Everything turned out to be ok. Thanks for your help!